# Initialised character arrays point to same memory

Tags: c, arrays, unix

I am doing an exercise on using UNIX System commands and I am trying to read two files from the start character-by-character. When characters differ program should print the remaining characters from both files and the position where characters started to differ.

Ex. ex1.txt has "My name is Carl" and ex2.txt has "My name is John". 
Program prints "Carl" for ex1 and "John" for ex2.

My program does the reading and position information but I have problems with initializing the read buffers and comparing them.

I am initializing two one sized char arrays but when I use read method variable `buf2` gets both of the files characters at current position. This implicates that `buf` and `buf2` point to same memory. Should I allocate memory dynamically for my char arrays or is there any other way to do this?

Moreso: How can `buf2` contain two characters if it's size is only 1?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define B_SIZE 1

void err_exit(char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
int file, file2, size, size2;
char buf[B_SIZE], buf2[B_SIZE];
off_t pos, pos2;

if (argc != 3) err_exit("Enter two files as arguments");
if ((file = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1) err_exit("Cant open file 1");
if ((file2 = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY)) == -1) err_exit("Cant open file 2");

size = lseek(file, B_SIZE, SEEK_END);
size2 = lseek(file2, B_SIZE, SEEK_END);
pos = lseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
pos2 = lseek(file2, 0, SEEK_SET);

printf("\n\nPOS: %d, %d  SIZE: %d, %d\n", pos, pos2, size, size2);
pread(file, &buf, B_SIZE, pos);
pread(file2, &buf2, B_SIZE, pos2);

while( ((pos = lseek(file, B_SIZE, SEEK_CUR)) < size)
&& ((pos2 = lseek(file2, B_SIZE, SEEK_CUR)) < size2) )
 {
    printf("Searching first different char: POS: %d\nChar: %s, %s\n", pos, buf, buf2);
    printf("Is buf same as buf2: %d\n", (strcmp(buf, buf2)));
    pread(file, &buf, B_SIZE, pos);
    pread(file2, &buf2, B_SIZE, pos2);

} 

if ((size == size2) && (pos == pos2)){
    printf("Files are the same\n");
} else {
    printf("\nNot same anymore. POS: %d\n", pos);
    printf("Print file 1 starting from this position\n");
    while( ((pos = lseek(file, B_SIZE, SEEK_CUR)) < size) ){
        pread(file, &buf, B_SIZE, pos);
        printf("%s", buf);
    }
    printf("\n\nPrint file 2 starting from this position\n");
    while( ((pos2 = lseek(file2, B_SIZE, SEEK_CUR)) < size2) ){
        pread(file2, &buf, B_SIZE, pos2);
        printf("%s", buf);
    }
}




close(file);
close(file2);
return 0;
}
```

Example of input:
[image: Output of program]

Comment: C have no bounds checking. Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Your buffer is only 1 character in size. That can only hold the empty string (`'\0'`) and `strcmp` on any other string in it is not possible (there canot be any other string in a  buffer of that size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are violating the string concept.
 Example:

```
strcmp(buf, buf2)
```

A string **must** be zero-terminated. If you pass a `char*` to a function expecting a string, you **must** make sure that it points to a zero-terminated string.

The size of your buffers are only 1 so there is no room for a zero-termination. Consequently you do illegal function calls and have undefined behavior.

You could try this:

```
char buf[B_SIZE+1], buf2[B_SIZE+1];
buf[B_SIZE] = '\0';
buf2[B_SIZE] = '\0';
```

but if you want to read char-by-char why not read into char variables. Chars can be compared using `==` which is much faster and simpler than `strcmp`